# Can a drop down in Excel show long descriptions when clicked, but only a short code once selected?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I have created a drop down menu in Excel, but the options are long sentences. After someone selected one of the options I want a letter to appear instead of the entire option. How would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do exactly as you ask, but you could try the input message feature of excel's data validation. You'll get an info box that looks something like this:

```
A: Long option 1
B: Long option 2
C: Long option 3
```

This tooltip-style info box is shown as long as the cell is selected. Also, to my knowledge, it has no size contraints, meaning that your options can be as long as you like.

Of course, the drop-down selection can contain just the abbreviations 'A', 'B', and 'C'.